# Show that $a^4+b^4\geq \frac18$ given that $a+b=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Show that $a^4+b^4\geq \frac18$ given that $a+b=1$

$$b=1-a\Rightarrow a^4+b^4=2a^4-4a^3+6a^2-4a+1$$
If we try to find the minimum of a one-variable function,we must solve a 3rd degree equation,on the other hand making perfect squares seems somewhat difficult!
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: by the [generalized mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Definition): $\;\displaystyle \sqrt[4]{\frac{a^4+b^4}{2}} \ge \frac{a+b}{2}\,$.